# How does the Mongo oplog work for sharded clusters?

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka-connect

I'm using the Mongo source connector for Kafka connect, but I'm not clear on how the oplog is constructed for a sharded cluster.   Specifically, is there an oplog per shard?   Or how does that work, exactly?

The further background is that when I run my connector against the normal Mongo URI, I eventually get a ChangeStreamHistoryLost exception.   But if I create a connector per shard, I don't see this error.   It seems that a single connector can't keep up with my database activity across ALL shards, but connector-per-shard can.   Which leaves me surmising that each shard has it's own oplog.   But if I had any idea I wouldn't be asking.

Comment: Yes, every shard is a Replica Set and every Replica Set has its own oplog. According to [Change Streams](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/changeStreams/) you must connect to `mongos`, not to individual shards.

Comment: If I shouldn't connect to the shards and multiple connector tasks are not supported, is there a Mongo recommendation for how to parallelize my connector to avoid the connector falling behind?